# Imagem não está centralizando

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Galera, já tentei de várias formas, mas a imagem não está centralizando.Segue abaixo o código para entender melhor o problema:

```css
.logo2 {
     color: pink;
     position: absolute;
     margin: 0 auto !important;
     float: none !important;
    
     z-index: 1001;
     border-radius: 100%;
     text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">    
        <div class="col-md-12 logo2">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go65r.png" class="img-responsive"/> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui está a imagem:
[image]

Comment: Corrigindo o código CSS:
.logo2 {
    color: pink;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    float: none !important;
    z-index: 1001;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
   
}

Comment: Renan você pode explicar porque é que a pergunta e a resposta tem o mesmo CSS? Não tem muita lógica fazer uma pergunta que está certa e dar a mesma resposta. Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Desculpas Jorge. É pq achei q eu nao tinha colocado todo o código CSS na pergunta. Erro meu!

Comment: Renan sem problema, quando for assim pode [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar ou alterar o que necessitar.

Answer (score 0):

Se a classe `.logo2` é a tentativa de centralizar a imagem pode excluí-la.

Adicione no seu css o seguinte estilo para a tag `<img>`

```
img{
 width:100%;
}
```

*Observação: Se essa imagem for a tentativa de fazer um menu, você com toda certeza está indo pelo caminho mais difícil.*

Answer (score 0):

Realmente o header precisa estar em position: absolute?

Aparentemente você pode deixar o background em uma div e dividir o header em 3 colunas, colocando o primeiro menu na coluna 1, a imagem centralizada na coluna 2 e o terceiro menu na coluna 3.

Ou pode ir além e colocar tudo em uma ul usando o :nth-child.